# Spring boot + Spring Integration Websocket adapter + Tibco JMS Server

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I am working to build an application (Server side) which should pick message from tibco jms queue and then post that to a url at which the Client (written in angular js) will listen, and also from client when some actions are taken then the server should listen to those actions and perform respective actions.

I can read from tibco jms queue and can place it to a spring integration channel.

My question here is that, can this be build using spring integration websocket adaptors (inbound & outbound) ? If yes then can someone help me with some references for sending to the client and receiving from the client adaptor configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

All the info about Spring Integration Websocket module is in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/web-sockets.html).

You also can take a look to a couple samples:

- [Simple plain Websockets](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/web-sockets)
- [Chat based on STOMP protocol](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat)